# If $f\in L^\infty(X,\mu)$ which is the necesary and sufficient condition so that it is satisfied $\frac{1}{f}\in L^\infty(X,\mu)$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, measurable-functions

Let $f\in L^\infty(X,\mu)$.  which is the necesary and sufficient condition so that it is satisfied  $\displaystyle\frac{1}{f}\in L^\infty(X,\mu)$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you have some particular condition in mind?

Comment: "Bounded away from zero" is the usual phrase.

Comment: @jgon...the question is what is the conditions over $f$ for that $\frac{1}{f} \in L^\infty(X,\mu)$.

Comment: The condition that f is essentially bounded has no relevance to $\frac 1 f $ being essentially bounded. No useful sufficient condition is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f\in L^\infty(X,\mu)$. We prove: $$  \exists_{K>0}: |f(x)|>K  \text{ almost everywhere } \Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{f} \in L^{\infty}(X,\mu)$$
First we do $\Rightarrow$:

We have $0<K<|f(x)|$ for almost every $x$ hence $\frac{1}{|f(x)|}<\frac{1}{K}$. Hence $\frac{1}{f}\in L^{\infty}(X,\mu)$.

Now we do $\Leftarrow$:

There exists $M>0$ such that $\frac{1}{|f(x)|}<M$ for almost every $x$. Hence $|f(x)|>\frac{1}{M}>0$ almost everywhere. Take $K=M^{-1}$ and you are done.

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: @Shashi...for you what exactly is "$|f(x)|>K$ almost everywhere"?

Comment: For example, one definition, say that, $f$ is not negative $\mu$ almost everywhere if $\mu^\ast(\{x\in X:f(x)<0\})=0.$ where $\mu^\ast$ is the outer mesure. My question is $|f(x)|>K$ almost everywhere if $\mu^\ast(\{x\in X:f(x)<K\})=0$?

Comment: @LuisPrado the condition is needed to make sure $1/f$ does not blow up. And what you said in your  last sentence does not have to be true.